# OpenCV Error: src.cols > 0 && src.rows > 0 in function 'warpAffine'

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am working on rotating the images by 5 degree using below OpenCV Python code:

```
def rotate_image(image, angle):
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
    center = (w // 2, h // 2)
    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, -angle, 1.0)
    rotated_image = cv2.warpAffine(image, M, (w, h), flags=cv2.INTER_CUBIC, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)
    return rotated_image
```

It works fine for most of the images but for some of the images, it shows below error:

`OpenCV(4.6.0) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp:2595: error: (-215:Assertion failed) src.cols > 0 && src.rows > 0 in function 'warpAffine'`

I have checked the size of the image where this exception comes and it's all good. Why is this error happening?

Comment: I think it is saying you have zero size.  Check the shape of the image before attempting to use.  Be sure you actually have the correct path to your image when reading and that the image is not corrupt or empty.

Comment: if the image's size were good, that assertion wouldn't trigger. please debug this again. try the debugger, try printing information on the terminal.

Comment: Sorry for late response. I debug it and noticed the image which I was passing in parameter had this value [None], not sure how but I have added the condition for this now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Using OP's script.

Your code is working with no minor change. Using OpenCV 4.6.0.

Comment out `#return rotated_image` in `rotate_image()` function.

Snippet:

```
import cv2 as cv


def rotate_image(image, angle):

    img = cv.imread(image, cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    (h, w) = img.shape[:2]
    center = (w // 2, h // 2)
    M = cv.getRotationMatrix2D(center, -angle, 1.0)
    rotated_image = cv.warpAffine(img, M, (w, h), flags=cv.INTER_CUBIC, borderMode=cv.BORDER_REPLICATE)
    #return rotated_image
    #cv.imwrite('rotate_image.jpg', rotated_image)
    cv.imshow('img', rotated_image)
 
rotate_image('w2.jpg', 90)

cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: were you able to *reproduce the error* presented in the question? how does your answer address the issue?

Comment: @Christoph Rackwitz. I updated Opencv 4.6.0 using OP's script.

Comment: OP revealed that the image was indeed `None`. your answer doesn't solve that. you could not actually reproduce OP's issue because it was *not reproducible*. that's no basis to write an answer on.